# PyQt - Display QImage red channel only

Tags: python, pyqt, channel, qimage

I'm working on a Picture Viewer and I want to be able to quickly visualize the red, green and blue channels separately.

Right now this is the working code I have but it's really slow since it's going through each pixel individually.

```
self.image = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
image = QtGui.QImage("C:/Users/Thibault/Desktop/title.png")
image = image.convertToFormat(QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
for y in xrange(image.height()):
    for x in xrange(image.width()):
        c = QtGui.QColor()
        c.setRgb(image.pixel(x, y))
        image.setPixel(x, y, QtGui.QColor(c.red(), c.red(), c.red()).rgba())

pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
self.image.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Is there any other (faster) way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: Manipulating images pixel by pixel in python is always going to be very slow. You need to write an extension for this kind of low-level stuff (e.g. using cython), or find a third-party library that already does what you want.

Comment: Are you able to use PIL (or Pillow)?

Comment: Alternatively, you could read the data from `QImage.bits()` to an numpy array, zero the other channels (array manipulation is a lot quicker), and then regenerate the image.